# Declare a variable as Control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, variables, controls, custom-controls

I am using Visual Studio 2008.

I want to have a DataGrid which is not found in the toolbox.

So I added reference to WPFToolKit.

Now I got a control named DataGrid in the toolbox.

After that I want to add a Custom control in my Project.

So I am trying to Create one which inherits From TextBox.

Here I want to declare a Variable like Below :

```
Dim Associated_DataGrid as DataGrid.
```

But it says DataGrid is not Declared.

So which namespace should I use here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added Referance Microsoft.Windows.Controls and it works nicely.